# Is it possible to write a program that is able to recognize some source-code as being its own source code?

Tags: cryptography, hashing, general

Is it possible to write a program that is able to recognize some source code as being its own source-code?

Biological organisms evolved the ability of kin-recognition, and later, self-recognition, early on. This led to the evolution of the immune system.

Of course the immune system does not go through the DNA of a potentially foreign cell one base pair at a time. Rather it recognizes certain "cues" that are highly unlikely to be the same unless the target is of self. (This acts similar to using a hash value to determine identity.)

However it has made me wonder if it is theoretically possible for a machine running a computer program to be able to determine with full accuracy and no ambiguity whether or not a given body of source code, if compiled, would result in the same program as the one that is currently running.

It seems to me this must be impossible, because for a given program to be able to recognize itself, it seems like it would have to contain a full representation itself. This seems impossible because there would have to be some additional code, besides the self-representation, to handle the recognition aspect.

However, perhaps there might be an algorithm capable of creating a guaranteed-unique cryptographic signature of some code, up to a particular size, which could then be saved into the program whose signature it is. That way if it's looking at some source code, as long as it has access to a way to compile the code, it can verify whether its own signature matches the signature of that code, and if so, it would know that code represents itself.

Indeed, we already use code-signing extensively to allow an OS to verify that a program hasn't been tampered with after it was compiled and saved to disk. However I don't know if such signatures are fully unique or whether they have collisions. I don't know if it's even possible to have a signature without any collisions up to a given size.

I don't have a use case behind this question, but I'm more just curious if anyone has thoughts on this or if you could point me in the direction of some recent scholarship on this matter.

Comment: Consider the simplest version of "compiling": just returning the source code, unchanged. Then it's a simple modification of [Quine](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine), but instead of returning/printing the code, you should compare it with the input. In general, it depends on the language you use: from trivial (you can create a [HQ9+](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/HQ9%2B)-like language which directly supports this operation), to messy (since it's like Quine (but with machine code), standard languages should handle it), and to impossible (not all languages can solve Quine).

Comment: @Dmitry, write that as an answer so we can upvote it?  We encourage people to answer in the answer box rather than answer in a comment.

Comment: @dmitry Are you saying that compiler that works that way recognize whether some code supplied to it was the code used to write the compiler?

Comment: It will be quite complicated than quine computing since the program needs to call the compiler on the given source with the exact parameters to make sure that the resulting output is the same as the running code. Also must handle the compiler errors, too.

Answer (score 1):

Read Hofstadter’s “Gödel, Escher, Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid”.

It is quite easy to write say a C program printing its own source code. Now reading any code can be a bit difficult, say if you are talking about operating a camera and OCR, but once you’ve done that, writing a program that reads code and detects that it is its own source code is not difficult.

PS. Oh well. Some people seem to have a very very deep connection between "own source code" and "halting problem". The question has nothing whatsoever to with the halting problem.

Assume you want to write a C program that can recognise its own source code. First you write a function that *reads* the source code. For example reading it from a file, scanning the text of a book etc. Let's say this function has a prototype char* readsource().

Then you write your C program. It starts with some code. Then it contains a line

```
char* source = "......@.....";
```

and then it ends with more code. Let "prefix" be everything up to the first quote in the char* source line, let "suffix" be everything from the second quote to the end of the program.  Then we replace the first set dots with "prefix", and the second set of dots with "suffix".

The whole program now consists of prefix, prefix, a "@" character, suffix, suffix.

What the program does is call readsource() to read its source code, and then it checks whether the source code that it read consists of prefix, prefix, "@" character, suffix, suffix. Very simple.

Comment: Turing's proof of that the halting problem is undecidable seems to hinge on the case where the code fed to the machine is its own code. If it could reject that case, because it recognized "this is my own code and so I'm going to reject it", then what happens to Turing's proof?

Comment: It's OK if you can decide on halting of  _some_ programs: e.g. if I see a "while (true) {}" loop I can definitely say that it doesn't halt. What mentioned proof says is that no program can be built that is capable on deciding if _any_ program halts.

Comment: Read the book. We are talking about totally different things here. I can show you 100 pictures and you can pick out which one shows you.

Comment: @scaly Turing's proof works unchanged.